# No registered JIT debugger was specified

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, jit, launch

I try to debug my application, i set `Debugger.Launch();` in code, but when process reaches this code then the message appears that

> No registered JIT debugger was specified. 
>   Click on Retry to have the process wait while attaching a debugger manually.
>   Click on Cancel to abort the JIT debug request.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Please do not use images to include error messages. Images of text are not accessible, look bad on phone sized screens, and are not searchable.

Comment: @Alexey Litvin, Did you find the real reason for this issue? If you get any latest information, feel free to share it here. My suggestion is that you'd better to disable the JIT debugging firstly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started repairing of Visual Studio by VS installer and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Please disable your JIT debugging in your side.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx

Note: You need to run your VS as the admin.

One possible reason is that it has the crashed or unhanded exception in your side which leads to pop-up the JIT debugging. So you need to disable JIT debugging and find the real reason in your side.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug on a machine which had VS 2019 installed, but it did not have the JIT component installed, therefore I also got the "*No registered JIT debugger was specified.*" message.

I had to modify the VS 2019 installation and add the JIT debugger under *Individual components* -> *Debugging and Testing* -> *Just-In-Time debugger*.

After I added it, I was able to debug.